# Why is Google Webmaster Tools telling me to update WordPress

Tags: updates, customization

Today I got a bunch of messages for many of my sites in Google Webmaster Tools telling me I don't have the latest version of WordPress and should update.  However, I have 3.13 and up; I don't see any updates on the WordPress page or within my site and 3.2 is there but it's still in BETA.

What's the deal?

Comment: Depends from where Google Webmaster Tools gets its information. Maybe from trunk?

Answer (score 3):

After looking a little further I found an article on the Webmaster forums page. It has nothing to do with your hosting provider as I earlier suggested. It is 100% Google. The reason is to assist webmasters in protecting their sites by keeping up to date services.

They need to make a few improvements since each time I've received a notification it has been about 1 month after I already upgraded. I guess it depends on how often they crawl your site. This is when they discover the version you are using. Another reason they might get it wrong is because I actually exclude the WP version as suggested by many, as a security measure. This could explain why they send me notices, since they don't know what version they must send a notice as standard procedure.

Here is the link to the Official Google Webmaster Blog where it explains the service:
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/11/new-software-version-notifications-for.html